# How to blackout area outside circle with OpenCV Python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have an image and I am trying to black out all the area that is outside the circle with opencv.

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd4D7.jpg)

[Goal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDR9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61758071/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Get the dimensions and divide by 2 to use a center and radius
- Create a filled white circle on a black background as a mask
- Apply the mask to the image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('jeep.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
hh2 = hh // 2
ww2 = ww // 2

# define circles
radius = hh2
yc = hh2
xc = ww2

# draw filled circle in white on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (xc,yc), radius, (255,255,255), -1)

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('jeep_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('jeep_masked.png', result)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('masked image', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask Image:

[image]

Result Image:

[image]

Comment: Marvellous! :) Worked very well.

Comment: I think xc and yc are swapped. It doesn't matter if the image is square.

Comment: `@nicomp`  Correct on both accounts. I have edited my post to correct that.