# how to remove background of everything outside circle in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**I want the color code of circle (rgb) for that I have detected circle but doesn't know further process to dynamically mask/crop every background except inside circle**

`````
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('4.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 25) #cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)

minDist = 100
param1 = 30 #500
param2 = 50 #200 #smaller value-> more false circles
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 100 #10

# docstring of HoughCircles: HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) -> circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() ````
`````

Comment: What looks 4.jpg like? Can you show it in your question? What is exactly your question? What have you tried?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758071/how-to-blackout-area-outside-circle-with-opencv-python/61758501#61758501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question finds the circles using `circles=cv2.HoughCircles()` method of OpenCV which returns in case of the below shown image:

```
[[[226.5 211.5 111.6]
  [597.5 364.5 108.2]
  [498.5 145.5  95.9]]]
#    ^     ^     ^
#    x     y     r      of found circles x,y == center and r == radius
```

Don't be fooled by the fact that there are float values returned for specifying integer pixel coordinates of the circle center in the image. They can be used as they are to preserve their precision or turned into integer values if necessary for indexing the corresponding pixel in the image to obtain its BGR color value (OpenCV uses by default BGR color format not RGB).

With the above results it's easy to create a mask by creating a new black image of same size as the original image `mask = np.zeros_like(img)` with white filled (specify thickness of the drawn circle line as -1 to get a filled circle) circles. With known coordinates of circle centers you can extract their BGR colors from the image array by indexing it with `img[y,x]`. If you want RGB just switch G and R in the color tuple.

[image: Circles]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('circles.png')
cv.imshow('original image: circles.png', img)
cv.waitKey(0)

img_gray         = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow('gray image', img_gray)
cv.waitKey(0)

img_gray_blurred = cv.medianBlur(img_gray, 25) # cv.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)
cv.imshow('gray/blurred image', img_gray_blurred)
cv.waitKey(0)

minDist   = 10
param1    = 30 #500
param2    = 70 #200  # smaller value-> more false circles
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 150 #10
# docstring of HoughCircles: HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist
#  [, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) -> circles
circles = cv.HoughCircles( img_gray_blurred, 
                           cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                           1, 
                           minDist, 
                           param1=param1, param2=param2, 
                           minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
"""
print(circles) # gives float values for x, y, r of the cirles
[[[226.5 211.5 111.6]
  [597.5 364.5 108.2]
  [498.5 145.5  95.9]]]
"""  

mask = np.zeros_like(img) # create empty black image with img size

white_color    = (255, 255, 255)
line_color     = (255,   0, 255) 
filled_circle  = -1
line_thickness = 3

if circles is not None: # found a circle or more than one circle
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles)) # <-- turn float to integer

    for i, (x, y, r) in enumerate(circles[0,:]):
        cv.circle(img, (x, y), r, line_color, line_thickness)
        print(f' Circle {i+1} center BGR is: {img[y,x]=}')
        # draw filled circle in white on black background as mask:
        mask = cv.circle(mask, (x, y), r, white_color, filled_circle)

# Apply mask to image
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# Show result for testing:
cv.imshow('image with marked circles', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imshow('mask', mask)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imshow('masked image', result)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

gives as output:

```
 Circle 1 center BGR is: img[y,x]=array([ 18, 239,  57], dtype=uint8)
 Circle 2 center BGR is: img[y,x]=array([ 64, 236,  13], dtype=uint8)
 Circle 3 center BGR is: img[y,x]=array([  6, 240, 105], dtype=uint8)
```

[image: Cirlces_masked]

Comment: Thanks can you please tell how to get color code(rgb) of circle background

Comment: thank you very much Please can you tell how did you found center of circles and their corresponding rgb at center

Comment: I have almost fully rewritten my answer to add as much comments as possible and gave some variables new self-explanatory names. Hope this will make it all better understandable.